# Intel Integrated Graphics driver problem on Intel Atom D2500HN

Tags: 18.04

my mobo is Intel D2500HN which has only 1 VGA port and no LVDS-1

my distro: lubuntu 18.04
My display: a FullHD Samsung LS22F350FHEXXM with a VGA and HDMI.
my problem description: 
tested on kernels
    4.15.0-20-generic: 
    4.15.0-42-generic: blank/black screen after a few lines appear after grub screen. Only the VGA port of display is connected. And the display's power LED was blinking - indicating no in-coming video signal.

```
~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller



~$ modinfo i915
modinfo: ERROR: Module i915 not found.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and remove the 'solution' part as this is a Q&A website, questions and answers should be posted separately. Then post the solution below by clicking **answer your question** button. It's absolutely fine to do that. Also removed 'SOLVED' from the title, that's not how it's done here. You'll be able to 'accept' your answer after two days. P.S. Also use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

First to make sure your firmware and module libraries are intact for i915

======solutions=====

make sure that both your `/lib/firmware/i915/` and  `/lib/modules/'uname -r'/` are populated with files
I lost mine due to `apt autoremove`

```
~$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-`uname -r` linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

====================

After which

```
~$ sudo modprobe i915

~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at d0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    I/O ports at 20d0 [size=8]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: gma500
    Kernel modules: gma500_gfx
```

and finally edit your grub configuration :

```
~$ sudo <your preferred editor> /etc/default/grub
```

`##video=LVDS-1:d`  is disabling LVDS-1 port which some kernel version might be directing the video to that port on default despite your motherboars might not have such a port available to you
So change the following line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1 video=LVDS-1:d"`
```

and then in terminal run  :

```
~$ sudo update-grub
```

my problem solved, credit due to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145648
which in turn drew his solution from
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.mageia.devel/13667

I had spent many days trying to nail this issue. Hope my findings are of use to you linux supporters. Cheers